# C++ program not printing?

Tags: c++, vector, printing

I've been working on a C++ program to make morphology changes to a text file that the user chooses, but while making this program I've ran into an issue where a different function that essentially does its purpose the same way as the other functions, wont print. Even though it should be printing.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
//look up line by line parsing
using namespace std;
void replacee(vector<vector<char>> &vec, char oldd, char neww)
{
    for (vector<char> &v : vec) // reference to innver vector
    {
        replace(v.begin(), v.end(), oldd, neww); // standard library 
algorithm
    }
}
void dialationn(vector<vector<char>> &vec, char suspect, char n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) {
                if (vec[i][j] == suspect) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                     vec[i-1][j] = n;
                    }
                    if (j > 0) {
                     vec[i][j-1] = n;
                    }
                    if (i + 1<vec.size()) {
                        vec[i+1][j] = n;
                    }
                    if (j + 1<vec[i].size()) {
                        vec[i][j+1] = n;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        replacee(vec, n, suspect);
}    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    fstream fin; char ch;
    string name (argv[1]); //File Name.
    vector<vector<char>> data;
    // 2D Vector.
    vector<char> temp;
    // Temporary vector to be pushed 
    // into vec, since its a vector of vectors.
    fin.open(name.c_str(),ios::in);
    // Assume name as an arbitary file.
    string argument2 (argv[2]);
    string argument3 (argv[3]);
    string argument4 (argv[4]);
    while(fin)
    {
        ch = fin.get();
        if(ch!='\n') {
            temp.push_back(ch);
        }
        else 
        { 
            data.push_back(temp); 
            temp.clear(); 
        }
    }
    if (argument2 == "replace") {
        replacee(data, argument3[0], argument4[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++) {
                cout << data[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    } else if (argument2 == "dilate") {
        dialationn(data, argument3[0], 'i');
        for (int m = 0; m < data.size(); m ++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < data[m].size(); n++) {
                cout << data[m][n];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    fin.close();
}
```

Note: the reason I'm so confused is because the printing method I used in the `int main` works for replace, but doesn't work for dilation. I don't see any major differences that occur between the two functions for them to not be printing. I even made a small test program and it worked in that one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
void replacee(vector<vector<char>> &vec, char oldd, char neww)
{
    for (vector<char> &v : vec) 
    {
        replace(v.begin(), v.end(), oldd, neww); 
    }
}

void dialationn(vector<vector<char>> & vec, char suspect, char n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) {
                if (vec[i][j] == suspect) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                     vec[i-1][j] = n;
                    }
                    if (j > 0) {
                     vec[i][j-1] = n;
                    }
                    if (i + 1<vec.size()) {
                        vec[i+1][j] = n;
                    }
                    if (j + 1<vec[i].size()) {
                        vec[i][j+1] = n;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        replacee(vec, n, suspect);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    vector<vector<char>> data(5, std::vector<char>(9,'.'));
    data[2][4] = 'x';
    dialationn(data, 'x', 'i');
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++) {
                cout << data[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
}
```

Since this is being done with inputs from the command line, they go as follows for the replace function:

```
./a.exe input1.txt replace (OLD LETTER NEEDING TO BE REPLACED) (NEW LETTER REPLACING)
```

For the dilation function:

```
./a.exe input1.txt dilate (SYMBOL IN FILE TO DILATE)
```

input1.txt is as follows:

```
.........
.........
.........
.........
....X....
.........
.........
.........
.........
```

Comment: For which function does it not print: `replace()` or `dialation()`? Also, you should check the `std::ifstream` if it fails or not...

Comment: Unrelated: `while(fin)` is a better [variant of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong), but still allows `ch = fin.get();` to fail undetected.

Comment: Print the matrix right before you call the function, to verify you are dealing with the correct data.  Also you should be using the debugger -- all of the issues you mentioned can be easily solved by using the debugger.

Comment: @Ruks for dialationn()

also, the input is from the command line using argv.

Comment: You should mention the command line arguments you are using.

Comment: The main difference between your two code samples is that the one which doesn't work uses command line argument, and the which which works doesn't use command line arguments.   Check whatever arguments you are supplying to the program.

Comment: @xannax159 Have you checked the code using a debugger?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie im using sublime with a linux vm, it doesn't have a debugger.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie

commandline arguments added along with testing file

Comment: More than likely GDB will be installed on your system. [If not, there's onlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)

Comment: Note: *input1.txt dialate (SYMBOLE IN FILE TO DIALATE)*  looks a lot like 3 arguments, meaning `string argument4 (argv[4]);` goes out of bounds and all bets are off.

Comment: I added a dummy argument `input1.txt dialate X y` and the program behaves as I expect.

Comment: @user4581301
i use argument4 for the replace function. without it, how would i be able to differentiate from different needed user inputs. The requirement for the assignment is that it needs to be one command line to do the trick. I understand where you are coming from though, but argv[1] is the file name. argv[2] is the morph, and 3-4 are the parameters required for the functions called.

Comment: @user4581301 just saw your new test, so is it not possible to use argv like the way i intent?

Comment: @xannax159 Declare argument4 where you need it then... that is, inside the `if (argument2 == "replace")`... and it will be automatically discarded after use... Because assigning an empty argument to a string will break the program immediately...

Comment: @Ruks that fixed it! Thank you all (i wish i could @ you all but it doesnt let me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given input of `input1.txt dialate X` the program invokes undefined behaviour when asking for a fifth parameter with

```
string argument4 (argv[4]);
```

Solution:

`argument4` is only used in the body of `if (argument2 == "replace")` so you should move the definition and initialization of `argument4` into the body of the `if`.

I also strongly recommend testing `argc` ahead of time to ensure you have sufficient arguments. `argc` is the number of user-provided arguments plus 1 for the command used to run the program<sup>1</sup>. Don't count on the user to not make mistakes. Meat-sacks are known to be quite error-prone.

Your program needs to make sure `argc` is at least 3 before getting `argument1` and `argument2` and `argument2` will tell you if you need an `argc` of 4 or 5 to continue.

<sup>1</sup> Usually. `argv[0]` may be left blank since some systems, usually embedded systems, don't have a program name

Comment: im new to c++, but what does argc do?

Comment: The `argc` tells you how many command-line arguments you have, including the name of the program itself.